# $(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^q)^{\frac{1}{q}} \leq (\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

I tried to solve the following exercise, but could'n:

Let $x_1,...,x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $p<q$, then

$(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^q)^{\frac{1}{q}} \leq (\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$

Hint:

If one defines $a^p:=(\sum_{k=1}^n|x_i|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$, then
$\frac{|x_i|}{a} \leq 1$ this means

$\sum_{i=1}^n(\frac{|x_i|}{a})^q \leq \sum_{i=1}^n(\frac{|x_i|}{a})^p=1$

I would be thankful if someone could give me the solution to this.
(Or help me get there myself)

Comment: The solution is already there. $|x|\leq 1$ and $0<a<b$ implies $|x|^{b} \leq |x|^{a}$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Could you  be more specific. How do I get the $\frac{1}{a^p}$ respectivly $\frac{1}{a^q}$ away?

Comment: Multiply the inequality in the hint by $a^{q}$ and the take $q-$th rooot.

Comment: $(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^q )^{\frac{1}{q}} \leq (\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|)^p)^{\frac{1}{q}}=a $ The problem is, where do I get the p th root from

Comment: Oh I think I got it. $(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|)^p)^{\frac{1}{q}} \leq (\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|)^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$

Comment: Thank you very much!